# Capturing interrupt on both edges when it's set on RISING or FALLING

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, interrupt

I've been trying to capture rising edge of an IR sensor output. This sensor's Vcc connected to Arduino 5V and it has a digital output pin. I've observed the digital output pin on an Oscilloscope. It's not noisy.

When I attach a rising edge interrupt on digital pin 2. It somehow captures both rising and falling edges. This response is the same for when it's set for FALLING or CHANGE.

I've tried code at below both on Arduino Uno and

```
volatile bool caughtAnInterrupt = false;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin (19200);

  pinMode(2, INPUT);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), test, RISING);
}

void loop() {

  if (caughtAnInterrupt){

    Serial.println("Rising edge detected");

    caughtAnInterrupt = false;
  }
}

void test() {

  caughtAnInterrupt = true;
}
```

Comment: How much time between rising and falling edges, and what are you detecting, a square edge?

Comment: @MichaelT IR sensor outputs digital high when it has a object in front of it. So, it might be any time between rising and falling edges. As I specified in the answer, I found the solution. Probably I didn't observed signal properly on Oscilloscope and the signal had debouncing problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue with the reply by [eventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3443596/eventhandler) to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756145/arduino-attachinterrupt-seems-to-run-twice/29758314). Here it is;

> The problem you are having is because the button glitches are
>   producing many interrupts on each button press. You can find a good
>   description and a way of solving it using hardware here.
>
> Let me explain, when you press the button, the mechanical contact will
>   have a transcient state in which it will fluctuate ON-OFF for a short
>   period of time. The same effect might happen when you release the
>   button.
>
> One way of solving this problem is using a capacitor parallel to the
>   load. Another "easier" way would be done by software. The idea is to
>   set a fixed arbitrary time in which you don't allow new interrupts.
>   You could use the millis() or micros() library to set this time. The
>   code would look something like this.
>
> ```
> unsigned long lastInterrupt;
>
> void ngt()
> {
>
>   if(millis() - lastInterrupt > 10) // we set a 10ms no-interrupts window
>     {    
>
>     state = !state;
>
>     lastInterrupt = millis();
>
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This way you don't process new interrupts until 10ms have elapsed.
>
> Note: adjust the time to your requirements.